# document.queryCommandEnabled() option always returns false in MAC Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, safari

`document.queryCommandEnabled()` option always returns false
in MAC safari browser.

How to make it enabled.?

Comment: I don't know, but my guess is that they haven't implemented the functionality yet, and only added a "placeholder" method that simply returns `false`. The [Apple developer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkitjs/document/1633908-querycommandenabled?changes=latest_beta) page on the method is effectively blank.